# AngularJs web service user accounts

Tags: angularjs, web-services, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have build a web application based on Azure. I have a web api service as backend and angularjs as frontend hostet in Azure.

I want to create a login page with individual user accounts. After some reading I found different user authentification strategies. Some use SQL database for managing user accounts. Some use Azure Active Directory. When I have to use Azure AD and when SQL databese?

Answer (score 1):

my opinion is to compare what the benefits you will get

Azure AD:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/

> For IT Admins, Azure AD provides an affordable, easy to use solution
>   to give employees and business partners single sign-on (SSO) access to
>   thousands of cloud SaaS Applications like Office365, Salesforce.com,
>   DropBox, and Concur.
>
> For application developers, Azure AD lets you focus on building your
>   application by making it fast and simple to integrate with a world
>   class identity management solution used by millions of organizations
>   around the world.
>
> Azure AD also includes a full suite of identity management
>   capabilities including multi-factor authentication, device
>   registration, self-service password management, self-service group
>   management, privileged account management, role based access control,
>   application usage monitoring, rich auditing and security monitoring
>   and alerting. These capabilities can help secure cloud based
>   applications, streamline IT processes, cut costs and help assure
>   corporate compliance goals are met.

Do it yourself with your database,you will have to do all above yourself e.g SSO with Office365

So you have to ask yourself what your app does? and choose the approach fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

The application managing its own user accounts in SQL is called forms based authentication. It's how most internet applications used to work, but it came with a lot of downsides.

Users had to remember a password for each site, but often reused passwords across multiple sites. If one site got hacked and lots the password database, user's accounts on other sites could become compromised.

To prevent this, sites had to make sure that they stored passwords correctly (salted and hashed with a slow algorithm) and apply other kinds of operational security to protected the database.

Then token based authentication came along which let applications delegate the authentication piece to an external 3rd party. This allows users to log in to multiple apps with the same username and password.

Most of these 3rd party login providers like Google, Microsoft, Facebook etc. have specialist working on these services and are therefore more likely to be secure than anything you create yourself.

So, unless you have really good reasons not to, I would recommend using a 3rd party login provider like Azure AD and possibly others.